# IOS application window size

Tags: ios, window

Is there a way to write an app whose window doesn't fill the entire screen, where the other part of the screen shows the normal iPad desktop with the application icons?

Comment: what a shame, it would have been quite an innovative app

Comment: My guess, even if you where able to resize the app window, the background would be black anyway, because apple wouldn't even render the desktop while your app is running. Performance is everything on such a small device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't. When your app start, the root `UIWindow` to which all your UI is attached is full screen. Here's the relevant snippet of [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingWindows/CreatingWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH4-SW1):

> Most iOS applications create and use only one window during their lifetime. This window spans the entire main screen of the device...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

Longer answer - possibly but it would require the phone be jail broken, and whatever app you are attempting to build would most likely not pass apple's review process.